# Actionscript 3.0 Buttons Aren't working but some are

Tags: actionscript-3

Most of my buttons Aren't working but some are working. I'm not exactly sure why either.

[This is what most of my frames look like as well][2]
    stop();

```
main_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mainClick);
function mainClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (1);

mainX_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mainClick);
}

fact1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact1Click);
function fact1Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (2);

fact1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact1Click);   

}
fact2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact2Click);
function fact2Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (3);

fact2X_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact2Click);
}


fact3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact3Click);
function fact3Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (4);

fact3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact3Click);
}
```

Comment: what is the reason that you have added listener to **fact3_btn** and **fact1_btn** two times and why did you attached  **fact2X_btn** and **mainX_btn** listeners inside the body of callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you mean?

```
main_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mainClick);
mainX_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mainClick);
function mainClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (1);
}
fact1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact1Click);
fact1X_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact1Click);
function fact1Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (2);
}
fact2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact2Click);
fact2X_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact2Click);
function fact2Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (3);
}
fact3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact3Click);
fact3X_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fact3Click);
function fact3Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (4);
}
```